# dynamic image download

Tags: silverlight, image, download

Can you look at the code below?

```
   Image img = new Image();

   BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
   bi.UriSource = new Uri("OryxAntelope.jpg", UriKind.Relative);

   img.Source = bi;

   LayoutRoot.Children.Add(img);
```

It works fine.
But after I comment last line of code(//LayoutRoot.Children.Add(img);) picture not downloads.
What is the problem of this approach?

Thanks,
Vitaliy

Answer (score 1):

The image is fetched only when it is first displayed. That is occurring after you add it to the layout (and the layout becomes visible).

What are you trying to accomplish? The example does not make it clear what the end result is.

Comment: I am trying to download image from server and then use it with WriteableBitmap..I don't have to display it on screen.Should I use WebClient for this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [article](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/10935/35056.aspx). You need to first download the image asynchronously with the `WebClient` control, and then you will be able to use/display it as you want. What I've done is set up a callback function, since its asynchronous, and you could put your code example in that function so that you don't try to add the image before it's finished downloading.

Hope this helps!